# Migrating from active record/postgres to mongodb/mongoid and I cannot create/save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have the following models in mongoid(i.e., was previously in active record).Trying save product item group along with item selection option but I am running into no method "all_of" error.And I am new to using mongoid/mongobd with ROR.

```
class ProductItemGroup
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  store_in database: "cnc_product_ms"
  field :name, localize: true
  field :description, localize: true
  field :product_item_selection_type, type: String

  embeds_one :item_selection_option
  has_and_belongs_to_many :service_categories
  field :service_category_ids, type: Array
end

class ItemSelectionOption
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include SimpleEnum::Mongoid
  store_in database: "cnc_product_ms"

  as_enum :selection_type,multiple: 1, single: 2
  as_enum :mandatory_selection_type,  atleast_one: 1, many: 2

  field :selection_type, type: Integer
  field :selection_mandatory, type: Boolean,  default: false
  field :mandatory_selection_type, type: Integer
  
  embedded_in :product_item_group
end


controller /form 
class ProductItemGroupForm < ApplicationForm
  attr_accessor(:product_item_group)

  def create
    @product_item_group = ProductItemGroup.new(params)
    @product_item_group.save!
  end
end
```

on save!, I am running into following error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `all_of' for #<Class:0x00007fd96afea600>
from /Users/90srebel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing'
```

Comment: I don't think this is will solve your issue but defining `service_category_ids` as a field conflicts with the `has_and_belongs_to_many`. The field `service_category_ids` will be implicitly created once the `has_and_belongs_to_many :service_categories` is defined.

Comment: I did try without  declaring service_category_ids but I got the error no fields found.So declared the field.

Comment: NoMethodError (undefined method `fields' for #<Class:0x00007ff58cc23830>): I am getting this error if I don't define fields for service_category_ids.

Comment: weird. but ok. Anyway to solve your issue I would start by commenting out stuff (especially relations) until I find the the filed/relation definition that causes the problem

Comment: Okay  @Udi Coden.I will try again.  I removed HABTM association and it works. Any idea how HABTM works in mongoid?

Comment: First of all, can you please share the mongoid version you're using?
About the HABTM - this relation saves an array of the ids the "belongs to" on both sides of the relation. And... it should be defined on both sides of the relation.

Comment: I am using  mongoid 7.1.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217789/discussion-between-90srebel-and-udi-cohen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the issue. I am closing this question.
What I did wrong was,
I declared has_and_belongs_to_many in product_item_group model but forgot to declare the same thing in service_category model. Silly